# How to make Linq extension methods available on ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I've written a class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>`. I would like to be able to use the LINQ extensions methods like `FirstOrDefault`, like what you may get if you inherit from an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`, or `List<T>`. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you added "using System.Linq;" to the top of your code file?  The LINQ extensions should show up just fine.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks David!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObservableCollection is based on Collection which implements IEnumerable. You are probably just missing the using statement.

You might find it useful to use a VS addon like resharper which works all these things out for you, suggests fixes, improvements etc to your code (e.g. you type .First() and a tooltip appears saying "press alt+enter to add a reference to System.Linq") very very handy. I could never live without it now.

Comment: That is a using *directive* - a using *statement* is the IDisposable thing.